# SQL order by two sets of criteria for the same column

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

Saved in my SQLite database table, I have a column that represents file sizes in human-friendly form. For example the value in the size column can be like 20.5mb or 350kb or 900b. I want to know how use the order by query to first order the file sizes first by size.

Currently, I can order by tb, gb, mb, kb, b. So they are in generally the right order. However, within ordering them by file size unit, I need them to be ordered completely correctly by file size. This is my current query

```
SELECT * FROM filtered
ORDER BY case when size like '%TB%'  then 1
                when size like '%GB%' then 2
              when size like '%MB%' then 3 
              when size like '%kB%' then 4
              when size like '%B%' then 5
              else 6
   end
```

The order this returns the rows in is like 90MB, 50MB, 50.5MB, 62KB, 135kb.

There are a few problems here. The first is the 50 would come before 50.5. The second is the 9 would come before 100 because of​ the first digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQLite** implicitly converts string literals to numbers when you apply arithmetic operations to them like addition.
So it will convert `50MB` to `50` when you do something like:
`50MB + 0`.
 
So the result of the addition will be `50`.
So you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM filtered 
ORDER BY 
case 
  when size like '%TB%' then 1 
  when size like '%GB%' then 2 
  when size like '%MB%' then 3 
  when size like '%kB%' then 4 
  when size like '%B%' then 5 
  else 6 
end,
size + 0 desc
```

Or with only 1 level of sorting:

```
SELECT * FROM filtered 
ORDER BY 
size * case 
  when size like '%TB%' then 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 
  when size like '%GB%' then 1024 * 1024 * 1024
  when size like '%MB%' then 1024 * 1024 
  when size like '%kB%' then 1024 
  when size like '%B%' then 1 
  else 1 
end desc
```

Comment: The one with only one level of sorting is really clean. Wow. How does that work? What are the 1024s doing?

Comment: 1TB = 1024 GB, 1GB =1024 MB, 1MB = 1024 KB and 1KB = 1024 B.

Answer (score 1):

You can `CAST` the `size` to a `FLOAT` (since it starts with a number) and then use that as a secondary `ORDER BY` criteria i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM filtered
ORDER BY case when size like '%TB%'  then 1
              when size like '%GB%' then 2
              when size like '%MB%' then 3 
              when size like '%kB%' then 4
              when size like '%B%' then 5
              else 6
         end, CAST(size AS FLOAT) DESC
```